# Incorrect Missing Email using EWS to get an email based on SearchFilters

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have created the method bellow. 
This method should return the email i search for based on some criteria. For some emails it works as expected and does return the email i search for but for others it doesn't.

For example if i search for an email with title "SomeTitle" with sender "some@sender.com" and for received time "2019/01/01 12:05:05" it works fine.

Then i search for another email with title "SomeOtherTitle" with sender "someother@sender.com" and for received time "2019/02/02 11:02:02" it does not work.

I can open the inbox at https://outlook.office365.com/mail and verify that the email i am searching is there but it does not get found for some reason i cannot understand.

The method:

```
private FindItemsResults<Item> GetEmailItems(
            CustomObjClass e)
        {
            var itemView = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
            var searchCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
            var filter1 = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeReceived, e.EmailReceivedDateTime.AddSeconds(-1));
            searchCollection.Add(filter1);
            var filter2 = new SearchFilter.IsLessThanOrEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeReceived, e.EmailReceivedDateTime.AddSeconds(1));
            searchCollection.Add(filter2);
            var filter3 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.From, new EmailAddress(e.SenderEmail));
            searchCollection.Add(filter3);
            if (e.Subject == null)
            {
                searchCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.Exists(EmailMessageSchema.Subject)));
            }
            else
            {
                searchCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, e.Subject));
            }
            var emailItems = ExchangeService.FindItems(
                new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox(ExchangeMailServerOptions.User)),
                searchCollection,
                itemView
            );
            return emailItems;
    }
```

I have tried lot of different things but my imagination run out. Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Please explain what you want to achive. I don’t understand your question.

Comment: @AndreasSchmidt Added an example in the questions. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to achive with filter1 and filter2 by using the Logical.And Operator. Please show me the value from the CustomObjClass...

Comment: @AndreasSchmidt It just makes sure that the received time is matched due to milliseconds accuracy not supported. However, even if i remove those two filters the code behaves exactly the same as i described in this question.

Comment: Please Remove the line `searchCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.Exists(EmailMessageSchema.Subject)));` and try it again. Please also provide some more information about your **CustomObjClass**.

Comment: @AndreasSchmidt I have already tried that but the problem remains